# WM_PAINT message is queued message or Nonqueued Messages?

Tags: windows, winapi

In this article [About Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it was said that WM_PAINT is kind of Queued Messages.

Queued Messages

> Whenever the user moves the mouse, clicks the mouse buttons, or types
> on the keyboard, the device driver for the mouse or keyboard converts
> the input into messages and places them in the system message queue.
> The system removes the messages, one at a time, from the system
> message queue, examines them to determine the destination window, and
> then posts them to the message queue of the thread that created the
> destination window. A thread's message queue receives all mouse and
> keyboard messages for the windows created by the thread. The thread
> removes messages from its queue and directs the system to send them to
> the appropriate window procedure for processing.
>
> With the exception of the WM_PAINT message, the WM_TIMER message, and the WM_QUIT message,
> the system always posts messages at the end of a message queue. This
> ensures that a window receives its input messages in the proper first
> in, first out (FIFO) sequence. The WM_PAINT message, the WM_TIMER
> message, and the WM_QUIT message, however, are kept in the queue and
> are forwarded to the window procedure only when the queue contains no
> other messages. In addition, multiple WM_PAINT messages for the same
> window are combined into a single WM_PAINT message, consolidating all
> invalid parts of the client area into a single area. Combining
> WM_PAINT messages reduces the number of times a window must redraw the
> contents of its client area.

But according to the book "programming windows"

> However, the window procedure could call a function that sends the
> window procedure another message, in which case the window procedure
> must finish processing the second message before the function call
> returns, at which time the window procedure proceeds with the original
> message. For example, when a window procedure calls UpdateWindow,
> Windows calls the window procedure with a WM_PAINT message. When the
> window procedure finishes processing the WM_PAINT message, the
> UpdateWindowcall will return controls back to the window procedure.

If the WM_PAINT is queued message, it should be added to the message queue.
so it will not process until current message and all the other messages in the message queue have been processed. which is controversy with the statement above.

I am wondering which is correct, Thanks.

Comment: Messages are sent, posted or *synthesized* from the window state.  WM_PAINT falls in the latter category, generated when the window's update rectangle isn't empty.  And there are no sent or posted messages remaining.  WM_MOUSEMOVE is another one, more obliquely, you don't get that message for every single pixel that the mouse traversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any message can be sent directly to a window proceudure using `SendMessage` or posted to the window's message queue using `PostMessage`. The `UpdateWindow` function uses `SendMessage` to send a `WM_PAINT` message directly to a window procedure so that the window is redrawn immediately. When the system needs the window to be redrawn for whatever reason it normally posts the message to the window's message queue.

So `WM_PAINT` isn't a queued (posted) message, nor is at a sent message. It's just a message. It either can be sent or posted. Some messages are only meant to be send or posted, but `WM_PAINT` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document about UpdateWindow function from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The UpdateWindow function updates the client area of the specified
>   window by sending a WM_PAINT message to the window if the window's
>   update region is not empty. The function sends a WM_PAINT message
>   directly to the window procedure of the specified window, bypassing
>   the application queue. If the update region is empty, no message is
>   sent.

Answer (score 0):

`WM_PAINT` is not actually posted on the message queue by the system, same as `WM_TIMER`. If you try to print `WM_PAINT`s from your `GetMessage` loop, you won't see any. `DispatchMessage` is not called on `WM_PAINT` messages.

I think it works like this: OS issues `WM_PAINT`s directly, always. However, if not called through `UpdateWindow`, it first examines the queue and waits until queue is fully empty, and only after this it calls `SendMessage` with `WM_PAINT`. This way, you still are able to process all input messages from the queue, before painting.